# Getting started with marching cubes in three.js

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js, 3d-rendering

I am new to Three.js and looking for a tutorial to get me started on how to use Marching Cubes in three.js. Some of the projects I have seen so far in three.js which use this are a bit complicated for me, so a simple tutorial would be nice.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about adapting it to three.js but there is marching cube code here if you want to try http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/blob/blob.html

Comment: I wrote a marching cubes algorithm in Javascript, to draw isosurfaces. Are you still looking for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at three.js and their marching cubes demo. It seems to have been built specifically for rendering meatballs :-)  I started fresh and copied over the lookup tables and rewrote the main functions and linear interprolation methods and got a new working engine working. My advice would be to do a rewrite yourself (it took me some time), but it will be a lot easier to integrate your own code with this new implementation. Especially, if you want to do more than just meatballs with a single texture. I actually used this site [polygonize](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/) more while trying to understand the Al Gore Rhythm.

Here is a video of it in action -> http://youtu.be/_oML6USPs20

You can track the release date here [highdensitygames.com](http://highdensitygames.com)

I'll be releasing the source once I release this game in the Chrome App marketplace. I'm not so sure it will help you though. It would be just like looking at the three.js source. You will need to dig in yourself with your own implementation. Good luck!

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? No source. Just an ad, with a reference to one implementation of the alg in C.  All other answers here actually get you started in Three.js

Answer (score 8):

Like yourself, I was looking for a non-metaballs example of the Marching Cubes algorithm -- I am particularly interested in graphing implicitly defined surfaces. Since I couldn't find one, I wrote an introductory Marching Cubes example that uses Three.js and posted it at:

https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Marching-Cubes.html

For more details on the theory, you should check out the article at

http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/

Comment: The provided link 404s

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not quite a tutorial but the [3 dreams of black demo](http://www.ro.me/) has a [metaballs sample](http://www.ro.me/tech/metaball-playground) with [source](http://code.google.com/p/3-dreams-of-black/)