# How can I create a surface file using multiple DICOM files in JavaScript using Papaya?

Tags: javascript, dicom, volume-rendering, papaya

I am trying to do volume rendering using one of the open source project. I want to create a surface file from my DICOM images. I know this is possible by using mango viewer exe; but I want to do it using javascript. Please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="papaya.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="papaya.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var finalImages = [];
        var images = window.opener.imageIds;
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
        {
            if (images[i].substr(0, 8) == "dicomweb")
            {
                temp = images[i].substr(9, images[i].length);
                //images[i] = "http:" + images[i];
                finalImages.push("http:" + temp);
            }
        }
        var params = [];
        params["images"] = [finalImages];
        params["surfaces"] = [];       
    </script>
    <title>Papaya Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="papaya" data-params="params">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Papaya only supports *reading* surface files (VTK, GIFTI, etc) not generating them.

If you want to do it yourself in JavaScript, looking into [Marching Cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes).  This is what Mango uses and I think is a common approach to converting image volume data to surface data.  (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550872/getting-started-with-marching-cubes-in-three-js) and also [this](https://github.com/PrimozLavric/MarchingCubes).)

Once you've created your surface data (triangles, indices) you'll need to organize it into a format Papaya can read.  [VTK](https://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf) is probably the simplest, but here's the complete list of [supported formats](https://github.com/rii-mango/Papaya/wiki/Supported-Formats).